# Response and response body for other than 201 status codes not found

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to fetch the error response from the graph api while creating the user on AD but not able to capture the response from the api for other than 201 which is a user created successfully.

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON }));
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    try{
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonRequest.toString(), headers);
        responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(graphUrl, request, String.class);                            
       }catch(Exception e){                                  
        System.out.println("Result - status ("+ responseEntity.getStatusCode() + ") has body: " + responseEntity.hasBody());
       }
```

Whenever the response is other than 201 it show me an exception Bad Request 400

I'm getting a error response with postman but with same payload the response is null in Java app

Comment: To get the error response in code, you could refer to [here](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/203).

Comment: My response itself is null. The quoted example has more about processing the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring's `RestTemplate` and Spring Boot's `TestRestTemplate` will on JDK's internal `HttpURLConnection` implementation by default, which fails to access the body of an HTTP-response with status 401 "Unauthorized". You could use HTTPClient which doesn't face the problem.
[image]

You could refer to the following workgroup:

```html
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId> 
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId> 
<version>4.5.6</version> <scope>test</scope> 
</dependency>

String token="eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Im5iQ3dXMTF3M1hrQi14VWFYd0tSU0xqTUhHUSIsImtpZCI6Im5iQ3dXMTF3M1hrQi14VWFYd0tSU0xqTUhHUSJ9.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.cFfptQOBt_BQKAbOSFsewmAMsgku15G8oKrfTuxD8ID2AZYtIWqEt1kFXKYBb66Hmsephe_KgyyeByIY_RLPW7JT3cpMTiSkh1DsiRvdAJJkZ0fcmgWQsZB-mmsS-Kt5vTUO1F5EtNeneaaklexfuEMG9E_hUiPKM2v46LlD3pO9ZPlq45157nUMcxPJlPpeHoE3riXwBEUQTCUFTm60NHOG1Cs_NuC_bVHBC3oN-pCFabz-vMo4O2Zikxn6S-BYxz909EP5lAmRNjKgH3uPYHS5rWfve20NiUPy8nOyBHKgz6XxAJXz7PVxm_hTOtdsGC9Hg8bdxnOKctPo95vAlQ";
String jsonRequest="{\"test\":\"a\"}";
String graphUrl="https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(graphUrl);
postMethod.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
postMethod.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
postMethod.setRequestBody(jsonRequest);
try {
    int code = client.executeMethod(postMethod);
    String res = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();
    System.out.print(res);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And you could refer to other information [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/441).

Comment: I have tried the above snipped. getting error 

    Cannot instantiate the type HttpClient
    PostMethod cannot be resolved to a type


Updated the pom.xml but still the app shows error

Comment: After some changes i could see the response as above screenshot for 401, but azure graph api has response code 400 where in if the user already exists the api will return an exact error code. I'm not getting that response now.

Comment: Cloud you share the error code here? What did it return for the `code = client.executeMethod(postMethod)` and `res = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString()`?

Comment: The code below worked for me. when I used 
 `String res = postMethod.getResponseBodyAsString();` worked fine when there is 401, but failed to capture other response like 400. 

Thank you for pointing me to HttpClient usage. It solved my issue.

Comment: @prabas, you're welcome. If you think it is useful, please make a mark for it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringEntity postStr = new StringEntity(jsonRequest); 
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault(); 
HttpPost postM = new HttpPost(graphUrl);
postM.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
postM.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +token);
postM.setEntity(postStr);
try { 
     CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(postMethod);
     int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if(statusCode == 201){ 
       String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
     }
```

The code above worked for me.